# Keycloak terminating session in the case of same user login

Tags: java, keycloak

if one user let say “user1”  logged in to application through one browser. If same user “user1” try to login again through same system or any other system previously created session should be terminated automatically and new session should create for that user.

How can we achieve this through Keycloak custom authenticator.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#implementing-an-authenticator

Answer (score 0):

Guess you must do this programatically in your custom authenticator. But this is tricky as you don't want someone not being authorized to kill the session of a user just be knowings his username. So you must ensure that the credentials are valid and afterwards remove all sessions. "Easiest" way should be to authenticate normally and then programatically remove all sessions and create a new one again.
But this requirement sounds like a workaround for another problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Events through Keycloak. Just implement your custom Listener Provider and on Event Login delete all existing user session instead current one.

```
public class SessionEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionEventListenerProvider.class);
private final KeycloakSession session;

public SessionEventListenerProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
    this.session = session;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.getType().equals(EventType.LOGIN)) {
        RealmModel realmModel = session.getContext().getRealm();
        UserModel userModel = session.users().getUserById(realmModel, event.getUserId());
        logger.debug("Removing existing sessions for user {} within realm {}", userModel.getUsername(), realmModel.getName());
        session.sessions().getUserSessionsStream(realmModel, userModel).forEach(userSession -> {
            if (!userSession.getId().equals(event.getSessionId())) {
                session.sessions().removeUserSession(realmModel, userSession);
            }
        });
    }
}
```